# Charles proxy not recording requests from PyCharm

Tags: ssl, python-requests, pycharm, charles-proxy

I am able to capture requests reliably from Postman with this configuration
[image]

But with the same config applied in PyCharm requests are not captured:[image]

We are using iBoss VPN but this should be agnostic to the application making the requests.
SSL proxying has been enabled in Charles and the relevant certificates are installed/trusted.

Why might PyCharm proxying be treated differently to Postman?

Answer (score -1):

try follow commands
uninstall urllib3 & pip install urllib3==1.25.8

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).